# Ajax and clean cache response IE8

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Ajax to make a call to my controller in order to obtain some information about a user.
The company is using IE8, and when a make the first call everything is fine, but the second call does not call my controller. I know i have to clear the cache, but i have no idea where i should put the clear cache with that syntaxe.

Anyone can help me on this one ?

Thank.

Here the snippet :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {id = @Model.id, idParent = @Model.idParent})"
           data-ajax="true"
           data-ajax-method="GET"
           data-ajax-mode="replace"
           data-ajax-update="#modalplaceholder"
           data-toggle="tooltip"
           data-ajax-failure="defaultErrorMessage"
           data-ajax-complete="initModal()"
           data-placement="top"
           data-original-title="@Tooltips.Edition">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </a>
```

Comment: IE is notorious for its aggressive caching of Ajax responses.you can set a global option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem. 
By adding the [OutputCache(Duration = 0)] on top of my action in the controller, i've solved the the issue.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
public PartialViewResult Action(int id)
{
 var viewModel = GetViewModel(id);
 return PartialView("_PartialView", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark your answer as the accepted answer (checkmark under the voting for this). That way, people will know it's the answer that worked